# Splash screen stretched in Orientation change in Android

Tags: android, splash-screen, android-orientation

I have created a Android application with splash screen. The splash screen is organized as like the below structure.

```
 res/
   drawable/splash.png
   drawable-port/splash.png
   drawable-land/splash.png
```

If I am launching in Portrait or Landscape mode, the splash screen looking fine. While **changing the orientation, splash image gets stretched**. Is there any other options to fix this issue?

Comment: Does it fix itself after a second, or does it stay stretched?  Also, are you overriding configChange in your manifest for the application (if so, it won't automatically reload the image on rotation).

Comment: Are both splash.png screens the exact same image?

Comment: @GabeSechan. Hi, Yes I am overriding the configchanges in Manifest file for handling the orientation changes for my application. If I remove that means everytime the application content is reloaded while changing the orientation. For that what I have to do?

Comment: @StephanBranczyk. Hi, Yes the images are same name with different resolutions.

Comment: If you override configChanges to not reload on orientation, then it won't automatically load the new version.  You'll either need to not override configChanges, or manually reload the drawable when one occurs.

Comment: @Karthick, You meant to say the images were of different orientation, not different resolutions. The images have to be of the same resolution in either case.

Answer (score 0):

The drawable/spalsh.png is not called, it is sterching the portrait image, you need to call on orientation change method and set the drawable port png.